# attribute 'onChange' of Input element rendered by state don't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, use-state

So my problem is, i created an function that when the user click an button an input show up
this input only appear when it press the button, but bofore the press it dont even exist,
the input when appear will have an onChange attribute that will work with an sate. The code of it is this:

```
const[newValue, setNewValue] = useState('')
const[editForm, setEditForm] = useState(<form></form>)
const[toggleEditForm, setToggleEditForm] = useState(true)

function showAndHideEditForm(){
  if(!toggleEditForm) {
    setEditForm(<form></form>)
    setToggleEditForm(true)
  } else {
    setEditForm(
       <form onSubmit={}>
         <input onChange={e => setNewValue(e.target.value)}
         <button type='submit'>Submit<button/>
       </form>
    )
  }
}

function submitNewValue(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(newValue)
}
```

So when the user submit the form entering an value, the console log shows nothing at all, but just putting the imput without the toggle part, everything works fine, so does the way i am doing don't work at all, or i am doing something wrong?

Comment: I believe the issue is not related to this specificly as https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-silence-6e2vw?file=/src/App.js is working just fine. Maybe, you should simplify your code and re-build it step by step.

Comment: Thanks bro, i'm still figuring it out what's going on with my code, it's very strange

Comment: So, ok, i remade the code step by step, and figured out that the function that does the submit for some reason don't work when the button that trigger it is inside the state, i still don't understand why